# Impact of using data shuffling in Pytorch dataloader

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I implemented an image classification network to classify a dataset of 100 classes by using Alexnet as a pretrained model and changing the final output layers.
I noticed when I was loading my data like

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
```

, I was getting accuracy on validation dataset around 2-3 % for around 10 epochs but when I just changed `shuffle=True` and retrained the network, the accuracy jumped to 70% in the first epoch itself.

I was wondering if it happened because in the first case the network was being shown one example after the other continuously for just one class for few instances resulting in network making poor generalizations during training or is there some other reason behind it?

But, I did not expect that to have such a drastic impact.

P.S: All the code and parameters were exactly the same for both the cases except changing the shuffle option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes it totally can affect the result! Shuffling the order of the data that we use to fit the classifier is so important, as the batches between epochs do not look alike.

Checking the [Data Loader Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) it says:
"shuffle (bool, optional) – set to True to have the data reshuffled at every epoch"

In any case, it will make the model more robust and avoid over/underfitting.

In your case this heavy increase of accuracy (from the lack of awareness of the dataset) probably is due to how the dataset is "organised" as maybe, as an example, each category goes to a different batch, and in every epoch, a batch contains the same category, which derives to a very bad accuracy when you are testing.

Comment: Just to add: Each class had somewhere from 20-60 instances and since my batch_size was 32, most the times a batch had instances of a single class with shuffle=False option. And this was resulting in such low accuracy scores

Comment: This is also as I understood it, @JosepJoestar.  But if that is indeed the case, why isn't `shuffle` set to `True` as its default value?  I do not understand why I would ever want it set to `False`, except in some sort of demo or tutorial where I purposely want a deterministic (but less ideal) result.

Answer (score 18):

PyTorch did many great things, and one of them is the `DataLoader` class.

`DataLoader` class takes the dataset (data), sets the `batch_size` (which is how many samples per batch to load), and invokes the sampler from a list of classes:

- `DistributedSampler`
- `SequentialSampler`
- `RandomSampler`
- `SubsetRandomSampler`
- `WeightedRandomSampler`
- `BatchSampler`

[image]

The key thing samplers do is how they implement the `iter()` method.

In case of `SequentionalSampler` it looks like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
```

This returns an iterator, for every item in the data_source.

When you set `shuffle=True` that would not use `SequentionalSampler`, but instead the `RandomSampler`.

And this may improve the learning process.